# How do I get date and time stored in a bash variable to update when echoing it?

Tags: bash, date

I have this script:

```
date_time=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
script_name=`basename "$0"`

echo $date_time, $script_name
sleep 2
echo $date_time, $script_name
exit 1
```

It shows me this (same time).

```
20200103114357, clone.sh
20200103114357, clone.sh
```

**I need** date and time when I call the variable as command. There are 2 seconds between next time, but time is the same. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code stores the result of the command in the variable, so it never changes. In order to store the command itself in the variable, you need some subtle changes to the quotation marks used, like this:

```
date_time="date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
script_name=`basename "$0"`

echo `$date_time`, $script_name
sleep 2
echo `$date_time`, $script_name
exit 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the date time after the sleep again:

```
script_name=`basename "$0"`

date_time=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
echo $date_time, $script_name
sleep 2

date_time=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
echo $date_time, $script_name
exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but no way run command again when I call the variable again?

Comment: @genderbee : I am not clear, can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I mean, I want call the variable as command in variable, so not write all `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`, but just call variable `$date_time` as command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want revaluate every time command is launched then you can concat the expression `$("date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` directly in the command that you launch.

Example:

```
cp myfilename myfilename-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

Filename output:

```
myfilename-20220928103450
```